# How To create slider/toggle to change font size on screen with HTML CSS JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

is there any way I can make this -->
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMkN3.png]

so I'd like to make a slider/toggle
and user can drag/slide it to change into different size (or point)

and for each point, the displayed text is changed
just like the picture I describe

do I use HTML5 canvas?
Or is there any way (maybe with js, to achieve that interactive toggle/slider manually adjust font size) for display preview?

thank you in advance!

Comment: You can do this in plain javascript.

Comment: can you show the link to tutorial, or how to do it in plain javascript? thank you!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/P6ExK/

Comment: @j08691 btw sir, is it possible to add different text for each point size of the font? like when it's between 12-18 px, it shows "small font size" text, and when the slider dragged to size between 24-48px it shows "big font size!" something like that? thank you in advance :)

Comment: Sure, that's very doable.

Comment: @j08691 can you help me how? cause I just screwed the whole script :/

Comment: This should get you going in the right direction http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/P6ExK/2/

Comment: @j08691 this sir http://goo.gl/JusWIs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this using just **plain HTML5** and JavaScript.

HTML5 has an input type called [range](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/range), and it behaves exactly as you want for this example.

*Note that according to CanIUse, the actual major browser support for `input[type="range"]` is: **IE10+**, **FF23+** and **Chrome 5+**.*

To achieve what you want you should first create the element:

```
<input type="range" min="12" max="42" id="slider" />
```

and then listen to its changes with js (I'm using jQuery for the example bellow):

```
$('#slider').on('change',function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    //do the rest of the action...
});
```

Here is a working example of what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/vNfh2/1/

Comment: You should include the jQuery code here as well, and provide the jsFiddle link for reference.

Comment: You also need to mention that `type="range"` [isn't supported in IE9 or below](http://caniuse.com/#search=range)

Comment: Is there a way to make this so that as you're sliding, the text changes size instead of it changing after you release the mouse?

Comment: @whackamadoodle3000 yes, change the event `change` to `input`. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/w4nfx628/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQueryUI's slider to do this quite easily.

Here is a link to the web page [jQueryUI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/slider/).

Put something in your HTML for the slider,

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

Then put something like this in your JavaScript:

```
$( ".slider" ).slider({
  change: function( event, ui ) {
    $(<text div selector>).css("font-size",(ui.value+"px"));
  }
});
```