# How to move slider of slider-like checkbox to one of its labels when clicking on them?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to make that switch slider move to the word user has clicked on (medium or large). I don't know if I can track movement of switch slider with JavaScript or maybe it is possible to do with css. For now, I have only created simple toggle switcher with changing color. The problem is that slider was customised a lot with :before, :checked, input and etc so I don't realise even where to start to make it happen.

```css
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }
  
.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.row-inputs-radio {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.item-size {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.item-size-eg {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgb(155, 154, 154);
}

.continue-btn button {
    outline: none;
}

.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  
  .switch input { 
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: -74px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    width: 187px;
  }
  
  .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: -3px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #13985C;
  }
  
  input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  }
  
input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(120px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(120px);
    transform: translateX(162px);
}
```

```html
<div class="column-input">
          <div class="row-inputs row-inputs-radio">
            <div class="row-input">
              <div class="item-size"><bold>Medium</bold></div>           
            </div>
            <div class="row-input">
              <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked />
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="row-input">
              <div class="item-size"><bold>Large</bold></div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: do you mean if you click on Medium you want the slider to move to the left and if clicked on Large moved to the right?

Comment: possibly check out something like this: https://codepen.io/emilcarlsson/pen/PPNLPy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How To create slider/toggle to change font size on screen with HTML CSS JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18315749/how-to-create-slider-toggle-to-change-font-size-on-screen-with-html-css-js)

Comment: You `<input>` doesn't have an associated `<label>`, making it inaccessible for tool-assisted users. Also, you are misusing the `<span>`-element for styling-purposes only, that's what pseudo-elements are for, or elements intended for that purpose, like `<canvas>` or `<svg>`. You can take a look at my answer to see [how to achieve what you asked for in an accessible way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65216233/13561410), meaning all users (mouse- or keyboard-users, tool-assisted or not) can interact with it the intended way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's go step by step:

- We get the `medium`, `large`, and input elements
- Add `onclick` eventListeners to them for toggling
- Add `cursor: pointer` to show they're clickable

```js
var medium = document.querySelector('.medium'),
    large = document.querySelector('.large'),
    slider = document.querySelector('.switch input');;

medium.onclick = function() {
  slider.checked = false;
}
large.onclick = function() {
  slider.checked = true;
}
```

```css
.medium, .large {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.row-inputs-radio {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.item-size {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.item-size-eg {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgb(155, 154, 154);
}

.continue-btn button {
  outline: none;
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: -74px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  width: 187px;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: -3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #13985C;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(120px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(120px);
  transform: translateX(162px);
}
```

```html
<div class="column-input">
  <div class="row-inputs row-inputs-radio">
    <div class="row-input">
      <div class="item-size medium">
        <bold>Medium</bold>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-input">
      <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked />
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row-input">
      <div class="item-size large">
        <bold>Large</bold>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## Using `addEventListener()`

The wanted behavior can be achieved by adding an event-listener to the labels to (un-)check the checkbox.

We can use [Event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_delegation) to only add one event-listener to the parent. We can use a boolean that tells us if the clicked label is the "on"-label (meaning, the label that should check the checkbox).
This boolean can immediately be used as the value the `.checked`-attribute should now have. Quick explanation:

- Is the label the "on"-label? If yes, do check
- Is the label the "on"-label? If no, do *not* check

In pseudo-code, it would look like this:
`checkbox.checked = isOnLabel`

We can check if the clicked label is the "on"-label by looking if the `.row-input`-div it is inside of is the last one.

**Note:**
Only adding a click-listener to an element which isn't clickable by default doesn't make it accessible.
To make an element accessible clickable, one would have to:

- Add all the appropriate listeners (click-listener, key-listener; specific elements listen for specific keys, e.g. a button for 'space', an anchor for 'enter', a radio-group for the arrow-keys)
- Make the element [ARIA-conform](https://w3c.github.io/using-aria/) (use semantically meaningful HTML, e.g. specific HTML-elements, `aria-role`, `aria-label`)

This can be quite a lot of work, so unless there is a good reason to create an element from new, one should stick to what is currently given in the [HTML-specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) (though it is easier to [read up on HTML-elements on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)).

Here is the snippet to show the result:
**Note:** The code also works for multiple `.column-input`s.

```js
for (let ci of document.querySelectorAll('.column-input')) {
  ci.addEventListener('click', evt => {
    let ri = evt.target.closest('.row-input'); // Get the '.row-input'-div
    if (ri.querySelector('.item-size')) { // If `ri` contains '.item-size' / a label, continue
      // '!ri.nextElementSibling' is true if `ri` is the last element
      ci.querySelector('input').checked = !ri.nextElementSibling;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.slider.round {border-radius: 34px}
.slider.round:before {border-radius: 50%}
.row-inputs-radio {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.item-size {margin-left: 10px}
.item-size-eg {
  font-size: 15px;
  color: rgb(155, 154, 154);
}
.continue-btn button {outline: none}
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: -74px;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  width: 187px;
}
.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 16px;
  width: 16px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: -3px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
input:focus + .slider {box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3}
input:checked + .slider {background-color: #13985C}
input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(120px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(120px);
  transform: translateX(162px);
}
```

```html
<div class="column-input">
  <div class="row-inputs row-inputs-radio">
    <div class="row-input">
      <div class="item-size"><bold>Medium</bold></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-input">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" checked />
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row-input">
      <div class="item-size"><bold>Large</bold></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="column-input">
  <div class="row-inputs row-inputs-radio">
    <div class="row-input">
      <div class="item-size"><bold>Mayo</bold></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row-input">
      <label class="switch">
        <input type="checkbox" checked />
        <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="row-input">
      <div class="item-size"><bold>Ketchup</bold></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

## HTML/CSS only

One could also make a slider-like element using radio-groups, where the radio-group would consist of two elements: "on" and "off".

In combination with labels, the user (sighted or tool-assisted) knows what both options of the sliders are, and can select one accordingly, either by using the mouse or by using the keyboard.
**You can try it yourself!** Tab to the radio-group, and press the arrow-keys.

Associating a label with an input-element has the following advantages:

- It correctly labels its input-element for tools (e.g. screen-readers)
- Clicking a label behaves the same way as clicking its input-element itself
  (the effect we achieved before using `addEventListener()` is implemented for associated labels by default)
- It doesn't require *any* JavaScript

For graphics, instead of misusing an HTML-element, I used [SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG) in combination with CSS.

Having multiple input-elements has the advantage of being able to give each one an individual value. This might be useful for submitting a `<form>`, so that the back-end would have an easier time figuring out what the values mean (e.g. a radio-groups' `"Mayo"` / `"Ketchup"` versus a checkbox' `"Mayo or Ketchup" = (true | false)`). This also makes maintenance easier, and the back-end wouldn't have to look into front-end code to understand the meaning of a value.

Notice the `aria-hidden="true"`-attribute for the `<label>`s inside the `<svg>`. That tells the browser to ignore those tags for building the [Accessibility Tree](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Accessibility_tree), meaning only the labels with the labelling content will be associated with their input-elements.

As far as I know, this should be *one* way to make the slider-mechanic you want fully accessible, for both mouse- and keyboard-users, as well as sighted and tool-assisted users.

```js
/* OPTIONAL
 * 
 * HTML-element can be used without JS.
 * However, one would need to manually add
 * the radio-names in these places:
 * - as <input>'s names
 * - prepend <input>'s id
 * - prepend <label>'s for
 */
for (var rs of document.querySelectorAll('.radio-slider')) {
  var rsName = rs.getAttribute('data-name') || 'broken';
  for (var rsInput of rs.querySelectorAll('input')) {
    rsInput.id = rsName + rsInput.id;
    rsInput.name = rsName;
  }
  for (var rsLabel of rs.querySelectorAll('label')) {
    rsLabel.setAttribute('for', rsName + rsLabel.getAttribute('for'));
  }
}
```

```css
/* Tool-classes (TC); DO NOT CHANGE */
/* TC: '.sr-only' */
.sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  border: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* TC: '.radio-slider' */
.radio-slider svg { /* Dimension of 8:5 */
  width: 2rem;
  height: 1.25rem;
}
.radio-slider > div {display: flex}
.radio-slider input:focus-visible ~ div {outline: auto}
.radio-slider input:focus-visible ~ div svg rect {fill: #2196F3}
.radio-slider circle,
.radio-slider rect {transition: 0.5s}
.radio-slider foreignObject > label {
  width: 100%;
  height: 18px;
  display: block;
}
.radio-slider .on:checked ~ div svg foreignObject:last-child {display: none}
.radio-slider .on:checked ~ div svg rect {fill: #13985C}
.radio-slider .on:checked ~ div svg circle {transform: translateX(calc(2rem - 16px))}
```

```html
<div class="radio-slider" data-name="radio1">
  <input id="-off" class="sr-only off" type="radio">
  <input id="-on" class="sr-only on" type="radio">
  <div>
    <label for="-off">Medium</label> 
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 20" xmlns="xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" stroke="black" fill="lightgray" stroke-width="0.5">
      <rect x="4" y="4" rx="4" width="24" height="8" />
      <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="6" fill="white" />
      <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%"><label for="-off" aria-hidden="true"></label></foreignObject>
      <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%"><label for="-on" aria-hidden="true"></label></foreignObject>
    </svg>
    <label for="-on">Large</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="radio-slider" data-name="radio2">
  <input id="-off" class="sr-only off" type="radio">
  <input id="-on" class="sr-only on" type="radio">
  <div>
    <label for="-off">Mayo</label> 
    <svg viewBox="0 0 32 20" xmlns="xmlns=http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" stroke="black" fill="lightgray" stroke-width="0.5">
      <rect x="4" y="4" rx="4" width="24" height="8" />
      <circle cx="8" cy="8" r="6" fill="white" />
      <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%"><label for="-off"></label></foreignObject>
      <foreignObject width="100%" height="100%"><label for="-on"></label></foreignObject>
    </svg>
    <label for="-on">Ketchup</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example, I did not assign a unique class to each side. And so I used the `forEach()` method.

```js
let select = document.querySelectorAll('.row-input .item-size');
let checked_pos = document.querySelector('.row-input .switch input[type="checkbox"]');

Array.from(select).forEach(function(selectCurrent, index) {
  selectCurrent.onclick = function() {
    if (index == 0) {
      checked_pos.checked = false;
    }
    if (index == 1) {
      checked_pos.checked = true;
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.slider.round {
    border-radius: 34px;
  }
  
.slider.round:before {
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.row-inputs-radio {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.item-size {
    margin-left: 10px;
}

.item-size-eg {
    font-size: 15px;
    color: rgb(155, 154, 154);
}

.continue-btn button {
    outline: none;
}

.switch {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 60px;
    height: 10px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  
  .switch input { 
    opacity: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
  }
  
  .slider {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
    top: 0;
    left: -74px;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: #ccc;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    width: 187px;
  }
  
  .slider:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    left: 4px;
    bottom: -3px;
    background-color: white;
    -webkit-transition: .4s;
    transition: .4s;
    border: 1px solid grey;
  }
  
  input:checked + .slider {
    background-color: #13985C;
  }
  
  input:focus + .slider {
    box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  }
  
input:checked + .slider:before {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(120px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(120px);
    transform: translateX(162px);
}
```

```html
<div class="column-input">
          <div class="row-inputs row-inputs-radio">
          
            <div class="row-input">
              <div class="item-size"><bold>Medium</bold></div>       
            </div>
            
            <div class="row-input">
              <label class="switch">
                <input type="checkbox" checked/>
                <span class="slider round"></span>
              </label>
            </div>
            
            <div class="row-input">
              <div class="item-size"><bold>Large</bold></div>
            </div>
            
          </div>
```